# What is the relationship between Java FX Application, Scene and Parent?

Tags: java, javafx

From the tutorials I've seen, each Java FX must have an Application which holds multiple scenes. Each scene is basically a holder for FXML file (or can be written hard coded).

But, when I tried switching scenes, I've encountered a problem with keeping my window maximized.

What eventually helped me was this [How can I keep my window size while switching scenes in Java FX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200224/how-can-i-keep-my-window-size-while-switching-scenes-in-java-fx)

So, my question is basically what is the relationship between Application, Scene and Parent?

Am I suppose to have a Scene for each FXML file or only one Scene and just replace the Parent node?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html): Is a single instance which creates the environment for you. It creates a `primaryStage` and launches the javafx ui thread.

[Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html): Is a window. You can have as many `Stages` as you want. `Application` provides you with a `Stage` in the `start` method, which has some special properties, compared to manually created `Stages`.

[Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html): Every `Stage` can hold exactly one `Scene` at a time. `Scenes` can be swapped out, but is discouraged to do so. It is better to just swap out the `root` of the `Scene`.

[Parent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html): A simple `Node` that can hold other `Nodes` as children. Every `Scene` needs exactly one `Parent` as the `root`.

FXML: Has nothing to do with anything above.

A single FXML file just describes the hierarchy of a `Node` (the root node that you get of the `FXMLLoader`) and it's children. You can have a FXML file describe a single `Button` or the root `Node` of a `Scene` and all its children. FXML is not bound to a single `Scene`.

If you want you can have the FXML file describe a `Label` and a `Textfield` inside a `GridPane` (like a standart input formular) and load it every time you need this arrangement somewhere (as often as you want, even in a single Scene).

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you very much for the elaborate answer!